# C++ covert a string to a long long, but the result does't correct

Tags: variables, converters

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
```

I want to convert a string to a long long, but when the string is 9333852702227987, it convert to 933385270222798**8**
    using namespace std;
    using std::string;

```
string addStrings(string num1, string num2) {
    string result;
    long long n1 = 0, n2 = 0;
    int length1 = num1.size();
    int length2 = num2.size();
    long long sum;
    for (int i = 0; i != length1; i++) {
        cout << n1 << " ";                                              //test the result
        n1 = n1 + pow(10, length1 - i - 1)*(num1[i] - '0');
        cout <<"+"<<pow(10,length1-i-1)<<"*"<<num1[i]-'0'<< "=" << n1 << endl;  //test the result
    }
    for (int j = 0; j != length2; j++) {
        n2 = n2 + pow(10, length2 - j - 1)*(num2[j] - '0');
    }
    sum = n1 + n2;
    cout <<n1<<" "<<n2<<" "<< sum <<endl;
    result = to_string(sum);

    return result;
}


int main() {
    string a ="9333852702227987" ;
    string b ="85731737104263" ;
    string s = addStrings(a, b);
    cout << s;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know why the last calculation get the incorrect answer and it seems not over the range of a long long. just a nobe, please help me.
[the result of the test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEfsY.png)

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol mentions `std::stoll` in the std library. If you aren't doing this for learning purposes, don't solve a solved problem

Comment: Maybe I didn't express my problem clear enough. I know there is specific library to solve this kind of convert problems, but I did the exercise not allowed to use that way, and I think my problem is not about the convert, it is way my result greater than the correct answer by 1, and I try to check the code step by step but I can't find the problem is, hope to get some advice from you. :)